# Winforms: How to render Fontawesome 5.10 glyphs correctly?

Tags: winforms, font-awesome

I have been using Fontawesome 5.6 (free) in a winforms project, and rendered glyphs by referencing the character code into a variable. "&HF084" would show the Key character in VB.net for example.

The latest versions of Fontawesome, like 5.10, while still having the same character codes for the same icons, don't always render the icon, even if it's available in the free version I'm using.

I have noticed in a few comments, that specifying weight would fix the issue, at least for css rendering.

Specifying Bold style under a label with the font does fix the issue of non-rendering icons, however they are rendered much more heavy than they should be. Previously specifying Regular font style used to work for all icons, however that is not the case now.

As far as I'm aware I can't specify weight of a font by point in winforms, just specify the style (regular, bold, underlined, etc.)

EDIT: For more information, I am using the ttf font files that come in the web folder of the web zip file of fontawesome. The reason for this is that otf file format doesn't work on Windows server 2003, which is an environment that will run the WinForms app.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Windows Forms? Isn't it a WPF application? I couldn't find any TTF font in fontawesome for desktop (at least in free version).

Comment: I am using the ttf font files that come in the web folder of the web zip file of fontawesome. The reason for this is that otf file format doesn't work on Windows server 2003, which is an environment that will run the WinForms app.